# Query into firebase realtime database through functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase functions and Admin SDK to implement a functions on a event trigger. I am trying to push a notification to user when a new update is available. So, when the update version changes from the current, I want to make some changes in the user object and set update_available key as `true`

Now, the location of event(update_version) that is being tracked and the data to be changed are in to completely different objects. The Object model is as follows:

```
|root
  |- app_info
        |- version

  |- users
        |- <uid>
            |- checker
                  |- update_available: true
```

Not so far I have achieved this :

```
 function setUpdateValueTrue() {
    db.ref().orderByChild("checker/update_available").equalTo("false").once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          console.log("got in here");
          console.log(childSnapshot.val())
      });
   })
 }
```

I guess this maybe completely wrong. At the moment i feel stuck. Any help is really appreciated. My major concern is how to I bypass the `uid` or query through it.

Comment: How do you link the app_info and the user?

Comment: No, not linking them. I am observing the value of the version. As soon as it changes, i want all the values of update_available under checker to be true for all the users. By default the value is going to be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work (not tested however).

Note the use of `Promise.all()`, since you need to update a variable number of `users` nodes in parallel.

```
exports.versionUpdate = functions.database.ref('/app_info').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const beforeData = change.before.val(); // data before the update
    const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the update

    if (beforeData.version !== afterData.version) {

       const promises = [];
       const usersRef = admin.database().ref('/users');

       return usersRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
             const uid = childSnapshot.key;
             promises.push(usersRef.child(uid + '/checker/update_available').set(true));
          });
          return Promise.all(promises);
       });

   } else {
      return null;
   }

});
```

Comment: Great. To be honest, I had the exact same logic in my mind, but the foreach loop didn't work for me previously. This totally works. I posted this question since I thought there might be a way to query through the data just like we have in iOS SDK. But this does the job. Thanks Renaud.

Comment: how could this be written in typescript?